# Fix bad files and streams with ffmpeg so VLC and other players would not crash

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

It happened me many times that I could end up in corrupted video files:

- video downloaded from official sources but with torrent and for some reason not all the pieces are there in .mkv, .ts or .mp4
- records in .ts format where at a certain point the data is missing
- copied videos from an old hard drive with damaged sectors

When I play this videos with VLC or other players they plays till a certain point and then instantly exits. Sometimes I can try to skip the bad part but I could meet another bad sector and have an insta-quit again.

Question is:

Can I fix this problems (I suppose stream and keyframes related) with ffmpeg and maybe in a -c copy fashion so I haven't to recompress everything?

What I want to achieve is a full lenght video where the missing parts are skipped, I prefer a glitch rather than having my videos crash.

Comment: See also: https://superuser.com/questions/538829/repairing-corrupt-mp4

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If parts of the file reside on physically bad sectors, or for whatever reason, the OS cannot serve the whole file to FFmpeg, then naturally FFmpeg can't do anything about that. You should get a utility which can ignore those portions and write the salvageable parts to a new file, like [ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html).

Now, if the file protocol is not the cause of errors, you can try

```
ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i video.mkv -c copy video_fixed.mkv
```

Comment: This works, but fails without `-c copy`.  Surprising that it doesn't work during recode.

Comment: Even with that, I'm still getting `Invalid data found when processing input` -- and ffmpeg gives up.

Comment: Nice solution... if the moov atom (on a MP4 file) is still present somewhere. What if it's not even there?

Comment: It works at my end with surprising goodness :)

Comment: Not worked:
`moov atom not found
video.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: This unfortunately consistently destroys any video file for me that I originally created with either OBS or ffmpeg

Answer (score 7):

In the search of a better answer a possible way could be:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -c copy video_fixed.mkv
```

However I'm pretty sure there are some extra options that can make the result even better..

Comment: Works for me every time I have some kind of issue with the meta data, timestamps, or container info. And it's very fast, usually faster than 400x playspeed.

Comment: This command saved my butt, to be frankly.

Comment: What does it even do it looks like a copy | paste to me?

Comment: @RicardoBohner do you mean the answer or the command? in case of the answer it was originally posted by me 1 day before the selected one, regarding the command instead it does a copy but also reading the data and checking for integrity fixes the stream.

Comment: I meant the command, and I didn't know that ffmpeg did integrity fixes when using the copy codec...thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested lot of solutions and software. I love cli commands, so using ffmpeg you can fix your video file with no hassle. Try the next command if you came here searching some useful fix:

```
ffmpeg -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 7561k -qscale:v 2 -acodec aac -ac 2 -async 1 -strict experimental ./video_fixed.mp4 -threads 0 -i damage_file.mp4
```

Good luck !

Comment: This will probably work, but the file will be HUGE! Better so just use H264 again, like: `ffmpeg.exe -i "input.mp4" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset slow output.mp4`

Comment: this is the only thing that worked. Can you please explain the flags? why does it work and how can it be optimized

Comment: I had a video which I composed of 3 separate videos with -f concat and -safe 0, however, while the result played in VLC, in Davinci I could only see the video up to the first merge point (audio was still fine, though). After that Davinci showed a red media offline message. I first tried simply ffmpeg -c copy to fix the video but that did not work, however this re-encoding worked.